# Is my validation code correct?

Tags: java, validation

I want to search a vector of object Employee by an employee mobile number. For a mobile number to be valid there exists two different formats:

```
private String valm = "[79][9][0-9]{6}";
private String valmm = "[7][7][0-9]{6}";
```

I try to validate the mobile number entered by the user to search for, if it is valid it is searched in the vector, else an error message is displayed. However, even if I enter a valid number, the error message is always displayed.

```
case 3:
            System.out.println ("Enter Mobile Number of Employee to Search for: ");
            String m = sc.next();
            Employee e = null;
            if(temp.size() == 0)
                System.out.println ("Database is Empty! Please Add an Employee.");
            else if ((!(m.matches(valm))) | (!(m.matches(valmm))))
                System.out.println ("Invalid Mobile Number. Please Try Again.");
            else{
                for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i ++){
                    e = temp.elementAt(i);
                    if(e.getMob().equals(m)){
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                        System.out.println ("Location: " + (i + 1));
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }
                if(exists != true)
                    System.out.println ("Employee Not Found!");
                System.out.println ("---------------------------------------------"); 
            }
            break;
```

Sorry if I do stupid mistakes, I am still learning and getting the hang of Java. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLostMind In fact, should be `&&`.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I have tried it with `||` initially, but that did not solve it. Why should it be `&&`, if only one arguement must be valid ?

Comment: Cause if the value matches the first test, it will never match the other, hence the error message. Your value must match NONE of them to be an invalid number.

Comment: You can write `if ((!(m.matches(valm))) && (!(m.matches(valmm))))` or you can write `if (!(m.matches(valm) || m.matches(valmm)))`

Comment: Can you add a few numbers that should and should not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment helped, so I'll write an answer.

Just replace

```
else if ((!(m.matches(valm))) | (!(m.matches(valmm))))
```

with

```
else if (!m.matches(valm) && !m.matches(valmm))
```

or

```
else if (!(m.matches(valm) || m.matches(valmm)))
```

As `!A && !B <=> !(A || B)`

This way, your test will evaluate to true only if `m` doesn't match **any** regexes.

By writing

```
else if ((!(m.matches(valm))) || (!(m.matches(valmm))))
```

You are assured that at least one of the conditions will always be true, as if `m` matches `valm`, it can't match `valmm`. The opposite is also true. This test will therefore always return true, and the error message will always get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

"|" is a logical or operation which will evaluate both the conditions and if any of them meets, it will return true. So with your pattern matching, say you have two phone numbers:

```
79000000
77000000
```

Both these numbers are valid, one matches your regex1 and not the other, so !true | !false will be evaluated as true and hence it will enter if block and will result in error message. Probably whta you are after is:

```
else if (!m.matches(valm) && !m.matches(valmm)) { //enter your phone number doesnt matches both regex

}
```

Here && will evaluate your phone number with both the regex and will see if both are valid then dont enter the if condition and if any of them fails then enter the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
private final static String VALM = "[79]9[0-9]{6}";
private final static String VALMM = "77[0-9]{6}";

boolean isMobileNumber(String number) {
    return number.matches(VALM) || number.matches(VALMM);
}
```

Maybe even more readable regular expression

```
private final static String VALM = "77[0-9]{6}|79[0-9]{6}|99[0-9]{6}";

boolean isMobileNumber(String number) {
    return number.matches(VALM);
}
```